# create a web server for local html using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I'm tring to create a simple web server to run my local html file, and now I can get a server running on localhost using code below

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'html'});
  res.end(index);
}).listen(3000);
```

But there is a problem that every time I changed my html file, the web page on localhost is still the old one, I need to restart the server to make the changes visible.

I want to improve that and I tried to use **koa** or **express**, like code below

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Application started and Listening on port 3000");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("test.html");
});
```

And I found that **express** can serve real-time html files, I don't need to restart serve when files change.

How can I use http moudle to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you read the file when the program starts up. Then each time you get a request you serve up the data from the variable.

Move that code inside the callback function that runs when you get a request, then it will be updated each time a request comes in.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'html'});
  res.end(index);
}).listen(3000);
```

You could avoid reading the file on each request by having the variable outside the function (as in your original code) and [watching](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) the file for changes (and updating the variable in response).

That said, using Express and its [static module](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) will provide benefits with caching and I'd recommend it over rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon).

```
npm install -g nodemon

nodemon server.js
```

Comment: Restarting the server is horribly overkill (and the question states that the OP explicitly wants to avoid restarting the server)